# Do not understand what this question is asking... or the notation, Discrete Structures/Relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let X = {1,2,....,10}
Define a relation R on X x X by *(a,b)R(c,d)* if a + d = b + c

I lose track of what it is asking on the part italicized. 
I have a similar question that ends in ad = bc as well with everything prior being similar.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I still do not understand, maybe someone could show me how it works with a different X, maybe X = { 23, 24, 25, ... 33} so that I can see how it works. I want to understand the concept fully, then I can apply it to the original X set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This relation is on pairs of integers.  $(1,2)$ is related to $(3,4)$ because $1+4=2+3$.  $(1,2)$ is not related to $(5,4)$ because $1+4\neq 2+5$.  Hence, some pairs are related to other pairs.  What you do with this information depends on what comes next.

Comment: So I would have a set of all the pairs of elements that relate in that way? (5,1) (5,1) would also be in the set?

Comment: Do the elements of the set have to relate that way with all other elements of the set? or just one of the other elements in the set?

Comment: $(1,2)$ is related to $(1,2)$ because $1+2=2+1$.  Also $(1,2)$ is related to $(10,11)$ because $1+11=2+10$.  All such combinations...

Comment: {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8)(9,9)(10,10)} so (a.b)R(c,d) works for all these, but if I put (1,2) in the set it doesnt work with any of them...
I feel like I am missing something here... sorry

Comment: You're right, any $(a,a)$ is related to any $(b,b)$, but $(1,2)$ isn't related to any $(a,a)$.  You're not missing anything.  It's not like if two elements aren't related you're doing something wrong.  Some pairs are related to other pairs, and some aren't.

Comment: So would R be a set of pairs then? Where each element is a related pair?

Comment: $R$ is a set of pairs of pairs, i.e. $R=\{((1,2),(3,4)),\ldots\}$.  $((1,2),(3,4))\in R$ because $(1,2)R(3,4)$, i.e. $(1,2)$ is related to $(3,4)$.

Comment: Yes, thank you I finally get it!!

Answer (score 0):

In words, what this is saying is that if you want to see if any two pairs of numbers in $X$ are related such as $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, for any $a,b,c,d \in X$, you find $a+d$ and see if it equates to $b+c$ if it does then the two are considered related by the definition of relation given.